need to reduce noise in Rodix Feeder Cube
Need to reduce noise coming through the control box. The Machine vibrates a lot which periodically disturbs the input/output which speeds up and slows down the machine randomly. The manual also suggest electromagnetic interference.
Was looking into an MOV for it but not sure how to connect. The schematic shown is the 2 boards in the box. Other considered options were Ferrite beads or ferrite cables. Any help or correction appreciated.

